Don't events have to be independent in order for you to multiply their probabilities?
Olivia has a pollen allergy and gets a stuffy nose with a probability of 75% given that there are high levels of pollen in the air. Normally (i.e., given that there are not high levels of pollen in the air), she has only a 12.5% probability of having a stuffy nose. One morning, the pollen forecast shows that the probability of high pollen levels is 20% in the city where she lives, but she still notices that she gets a stuffy nose. What is the probability that there are high pollen levels in the air given that Olivia has a stuffy nose? In the answers:
The solution says:
Let A be the event that Olivia has a stuffy nose and B be the event that there are high pollen levels outside

I assume they are adding up the probability that Olivia gets stuffy nose given low and high probablity that there is gonna be hogh levels of pollen. But my question is how can they do P(A|B) P(B) ? Don't events have to be independent for you to be able to mulitply them? Olivia getting stuffy nose given that there high level pollen and there is high level of pollen is not exactly independent.

$P(A|B)P(B)$ comes from the fact that $P(A|B) = \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)}$. The law of total probability states $P(A) = P(A \cap B) + P(A \cap B^*)$.

If it helps, you could think of event B and conditional event A|B as being mutually independent.

I think if you see where the terms $P(A|B)P(B)$ and $P(A|B)P(B^{\star})$ come from, you'll see why it has nothing to do with independence.
Event $B$ is defined as the event of high pollen levels. That must mean its complement is the event $B^{\star}$ which is defined as low pollen levels. By definition, $B$ and $B^{\star}$ are disjoint, meaning that they do not share any outcomes in common.
Since event $A$ is defined has Olivia having a stuffy nose, we wonder what part of that event happens when there's high pollen or when there's low pollen. This description can be written as
$$
P(A) = P(A \cap B) + P(A \cap B^{\star}) \tag{1}
$$
But we know, by conditional probability, that
$$
P(A|B) = \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)} \implies P(A \cap B) = P(A|B)P(B) \tag{2}
$$
and
$$
P(A|B^{\star}) = \frac{P(A \cap B^{\star})}{P(B^{\star})} \implies P(A \cap \tag{3}B^{\star}) = P(A|B^{\star})P(B^{\star})
$$
Thus, equations $(2)$ and $(3)$ imply that we can rewrite $(1)$ as
$$
P(A) = P(A|B)P(B) + P(A|B^{\star})P(B^{\star})
$$
which is what the solution shows. It has nothing to do with independence.

To answer your core question, let's recall what it means for two events $C$ and $D$ to be independent:

$C$ and $D$ are independent if and only if $P(C \cap D) = P(C)P(D)$

So, what's troubling you in the solution is that we have $P(A|B)P(B)$ where events $A|B$ and $B$ might be dependent. But notice how that does not contradict the definition of independence above since we make no claim in our solution that $P((A|B) \cap B) = P(A|B)P(B)$.

I wouldn't even say that $A\mid B$ is an event. Which set of outcomes does it contain in this question?

Thank you so much. I have been working with bayes formula so much that I forgot the existence of the usual  conditional formula. This was such a good reminder!

@DavidK good point, I'm not sure. How would you characterize it? Is it even an object (like a set for example)?

I just think of it as conditional probability rather than unconditional probability. It's not an object $A\mid B$ used as the argument of the $P(\cdot)$ notation; it's two separate events $A$ and $B$ used as arguments of the $P(\cdot\mid\cdot)$ notation. But there are probably other interpretations.

@DavidK: I was going to say (and did add a comment) that I couldn't think of a good interpretation of that as a "conditional event". But that turns out not to be so: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_event_algebra

@BrianTung That's what I meant by "other interpretations." I had not seen CEA before but I had guessed that something like that would be possible.

@DavidK: I was wondering how that would work in the original probability space and couldn't come up with one. I'm not really surprised in retrospect that ten minutes didn't suffice! :-)

When events $A$ and $B$ are independent, then $$\mathsf P(A\cap B)=\mathsf P(A)\,\mathsf P(B)$$
Otherwise, the definition of conditional probability is applicable. $$\mathsf P(A\cap B)=\mathsf P(A\mid B)\,\mathsf P(B) = \mathsf P(A)~\mathsf P(B\mid A)$$
